# Is there a way to trigger AWS lambda by another lambda and SQS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

Lets say I have two lambdas: A & B. A is listening to an SQS.

I want the flow to be as followed:

1. A message arrived to the SQS.
2. Lambda A pulls the message and starts working on it.
3. After lambda A started, lambda B also takes the message and does other things. But lambda B must start after A has already started.

I know I can use lambda A to put the message on another SQS, and then lambda B will listen to the new SQS.
But I was wondering if there is a better way to run the lambdas one after another.

Thanks

Comment: you can make your worker lambda (ie lambda A) invoke lambda B. if you want to decouple it, make your lambda A publish to an SNS topic and have lambda B subscribe to it.

Answer (score 2):

You can invoke lambda B directly from lambda A with Lambda SDK.

You can invoke a function synchronously (and wait for the response), or asynchronously. To invoke a function asynchronously, set InvocationType to Event. For example:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('lambda')
response = client.invoke(
  FunctionName='lambda-b',
  InvocationType='Event',
  LogType='Tail',
  ClientContext='string',
  Payload=file,
  Qualifier='string'
)
```

Documentation for Python SDK (boto3) [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#Lambda.Client.invoke)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [***Step Functions***](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/) service. It will help you to coordinate different AWS services (Lambda, SQS, DynamoDb, ...) into a serverless workflow.

This is a nice Tutorial on how to use them: [***AWS Step Functions — A User’s Guide***](https://medium.com/@serverlessguru/aws-step-functions-a-users-guide-f8d313dfdfeb)

[***AWS Step Functions Developer Guides***](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/step-functions-dg.pdf) is the offical docs that will show you all the things that you could do with Step Functions.

Comment: only issue here is that you would need to have a lambda that was triggered by SQS to StartExecution for a step function. So, one more compute needs to be added to make this work, but I agree that ANY orchestration of lambda should be used w/ step functions.

Comment: You could trigger your step function from whenever you want using the [Step Functions SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/StepFunctions.html). That could solve your issue depending in the serverless architecture you design. Let me know if works for you

Comment: yea...to run that, you need some compute instance (being a lambda trigger). You cannot start a step function as a trigger from SQS

Comment: Oh ok I get it better now. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53422296/aws-sqs-trigger-step-functions), it was discussed the subject about triggering a step function using SQS. It seems it is not directly possible

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke Lambda B directly from Lambda A.

here is a code for python

```py
from boto3 import client as boto3_client
from datetime import datetime
import json

lambda_client = boto3_client('lambda', region_name='eu-west-1')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response = lambda_client.invoke(FunctionName="lambda_b",
                                           InvocationType='Event',
                                           Payload=json.dumps(event))
    print(response)
```

Please remember: you need to edit your role to allow a lambda invocation:

```
   {
        "Sid": "St125642120",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "lambda:InvokeFunction"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
```